# Grails createCriteria MissingMethodException

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

We have block of code that selects a whole bunch of user id's (200,000+).
The code then loops through each getting further information.

```
        def crit = Subscription.createCriteria()
        def result = crit.get {
            projections {
                rowCount()
            }
            eq('userId', userId)
            eq('deptId', deptId)
            ge('endDate', new Date())
        }
```

We just want to know if there exists a record that is 'valid'. 
This works fine. Until we hit a record much further down the array. Grails then throws the following Exception:

```
2012-08-13 16:00:45,518 ERROR subscription.service.SubscriptionServiceImpl(?:?) - No signature of method: static com.me.subscription.model.Subscription.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.me.subscription.model.Subscription.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Why is this looping fine for thousands of records, and then this Exception pops out?

Looking at the code through the debugger in IntelliJ shows that all the parameters are valid. But when I run an Expression:

```
def asd = Subscription.createCriteria()
```

The method is missing. 
This is not a mocked method. This is running in production. Have I hit some top level boundary?

Comment: You're looping and creating thousands of criterias? Do you have enough memory?

Comment: Granted, this method uses a stupid amount of memory. But I have run this section of code through YourKit, and it looks to be handled ok. This method is a candidate for rewrite, but missing methods out of nowhere are cause for concern.